# Bundler version for Ruby 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv, gemfile

I currently have 2 ruby versions, 2.5.5 and 2.3.8, I am managing them with rbenv, and for gems, I use bundler to manage my specific gem versions. I have an issue when I want to switch to a project that uses 2.3.8 or a version that has to do with Ruby version 2.3.

My question is how do I get bundler to run the command to `bundle install` interact with my 2.3 projects.

My current version of bundler is 2.0.2.

I have already tried installing a lower version of bundler of which the bundler website claims to interact with ruby version 2.3.

I thought that if I specified the command to run `bundle _version_ install` it would work, but it still gave me the response that it needed ruby version 2.5 for bundler to work.

Lots of help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, isolation can help. I would like to recommend rvm (https://github.com/rvm/rvm) for managing ruby versions.  This tool is very similar to rbenv but in comparison, it allows you to create gemsets which are kind of containers of gems for special purposes. For instance:

```
rvm install 2.5.5 --disable-binary
rvm use 2.5.5@name-of-gemset --create
gem install bundler
bundle install # inside your project folder with Gemfile
```

I think that you will not have problems with versions again.